# Loop for Insert Multi Variables into List in Ansible

Tags: ansible, active-directory

I managed to get user into multiple groups using ‘loop'. However, I had a problem assigning the user to an uncertain number of groups. In my ansible-playbook below, I used a loop to put the user 'Cahbayu' into 3 different groups namely 'DNSAdmins, Backup Operators, and Remote Desktop Users' and it worked:

```
---
- hosts: brc.testlab.com
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    group: DNSAdmins, Backup Operators, Remote Desktop Users
    username: Cahbayu
    
  tasks:
  - name: split the domain and save as variable
    set_fact:
      group_split: "{{ group.split(',') }}"
      
  - name: show group in domain
    debug:
      msg: "{{ group_split }}"
      
  - name: "Add Member to Group"
    community.windows.win_domain_group_membership:
      name: "{{item.group}}"
      members: "{{item.username}}"
      state: present
    loop: 
      - { group: "{{(group_split)[0]}}", username: "{{username}}" }
      - { group: "{{(group_split)[1]}}", username: "{{username}}" }
      - { group: "{{(group_split)[2]}}", username: "{{username}}" }
```

A new problem is encountered when I declare a group with a number less than 3 or more than 3 which will display the following error results:

[image: Error]

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not required to create a list of dictionaries for `win_domain_group_membership` task. It might be enough to just loop over the `group_split` variable.

```yaml
  - name: split the domain and save as variable
    set_fact:
      group_split: "{{ group.split(',') }}"
  - name: "Add Member to Group"
    community.windows.win_domain_group_membership:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      members: "{{ username }}"
      state: present
    loop: "{{ group_split }}"
```

Or since you are defining groups in the `vars:` section, you can define the `group` variable as a list and avoid `set_fact` with `split`.

Example:

```yaml
vars:
  username: Cahbayu
  group:
    - "DNSAdmins"
    - "Backup Operators"
    - "Remote Desktop Users"

tasks:
  - name: "Add Member to Group"
    community.windows.win_domain_group_membership:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      members: "{{ username }}"
      state: present
    loop: "{{ group }}"
```

Comment: It has really helped me, thank you for such a detailed answer!